# Why a ZeroMQ Context is not being shared amongst all the goroutines?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, go, zeromq

In this [ZeroMQ example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/go:mtserver),

```
// Multithreaded Hello World server.
// Uses Goroutines.  We could also use channels (a native form of
// inproc), but I stuck to the example.
//
// Author:  Brendan Mc.
// Requires: http://github.com/alecthomas/gozmq

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    zmq "github.com/alecthomas/gozmq"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Launch pool of worker threads
    for i := 0; i != 5; i = i + 1 {
        go worker()
    }

    // Prepare our context and sockets
    context, _ := zmq.NewContext()
    defer context.Close()

    // Socket to talk to clients
    clients, _ := context.NewSocket(zmq.ROUTER)
    defer clients.Close()
    clients.Bind("tcp://*:5555")

    // Socket to talk to workers
    workers, _ := context.NewSocket(zmq.DEALER)
    defer workers.Close()
    workers.Bind("ipc://workers.ipc")

    // connect work threads to client threads via a queue
    zmq.Device(zmq.QUEUE, clients, workers)

}

func worker() {
    context, _ := zmq.NewContext()
    defer context.Close()

    // Socket to talk to dispatcher
    receiver, _ := context.NewSocket(zmq.REP)
    defer receiver.Close()
    receiver.Connect("ipc://workers.ipc")

    for true {
        received, _ := receiver.Recv(0)
        fmt.Printf("Received request [%s]\n", received)

        // Do some 'work'
        time.Sleep(time.Second)

        // Send reply back to client
        receiver.Send([]byte("World"), 0)
    }
}
```

each goroutine has its own ZeroMQ **`Context`**. However, in the [ZeroMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Multithreading-with-ZeroMQ), it says the following:

> Create one ZeroMQ context at the start of your process, and pass that
> to all threads that you want to connect via inproc sockets.
>
> Don't share ZeroMQ sockets between threads. ZeroMQ sockets are not
> threadsafe. Technically it's possible to migrate a socket from one
> thread to another but it demands skill. The only place where it's
> remotely sane to share sockets between threads are in language
> bindings that need to do magic like garbage collection on sockets.

I know that goroutines are not threads.

Instead, they live in threads. But I've also read that it's possible to have a shared object between goroutines.

So, **why doesn't the context is shared between goroutines?**

I think it'd consume a lot less space, because a context with a socket in it might be kinda big.

But even if it's not that consuming, **why at all the context is not shared in this example?**

Answer (score 1):

### Q: why isn't the context shared between goroutines? <sup>( in the example )</sup>

Besides the <sub>( rather extremist )</sub> technical option to indeed share a Context instance ( under some well justified circumstances / occassions ), the demonstrated piece of code has focused on a **Zero-Sharing, as a general principle**, the one of a few Zero-Maxims, the ZeroMQ is so well known for.

There are advantages of a habit to employ a group of disjunct **`Context`** instances ( which one may also have several of these, within the same thread, on purpose ). The performance scaling:

- in a wide meaning, the separation of workloads, among instances
- in a narrower meaning, a direct IO-thread scaling ( defining different number of IO-threads upon the Context instantiation, some having just 1 IO-thread, whereas other may have 2, 3 or 10 IO-threads for a high-performance Data-pumping engine ) and using a bit-mask mapping via a **`setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY ... )`**-based socket-to-IO-threads mapping, which allows to directly separate some transport-tasks onto different, discjunct  **`Context`**-instances, and also to more specifically handle different transport-traffic priority-modes, right by using the separate, specialised groups of **`Context`**-instances' IO-threads ( naturally, where knowingly equipped with more and different amounts of underlying ZeroMQ `Context`'s IO-threads ). This is an invaluable feature for performance scaling and almost-deterministic traffic-policy handling implementations.

This may inspire your further thought on how such fine-grained management ( granularity ) may help your distributed applications better harness the ZeroMQ framework's services and how this Zero-Sharing concept opens you the new worlds of performance scaling and throughput throttling.

If in doubts, just notice the inital remark in the source code:

```
...
// Uses Goroutines.  We could also use channels (a native form of
// inproc), but I stuck to the example.
...
```

The **`inproc://`** transport class is the clear example on how to benefit from the non-shared, non-blocking Context-instance and enjoy the almost linear scale-up, up to the peak performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely share objects between Goroutines, as long as those objects are threadsafe. The Go ZeroMQ bindings you are using is explicitly non-threadsafe. While a single Goroutine may not correspond to a single OS thread, it is not possible to guarantee that the Goroutines you spawn will live on the same OS thread. Their life cycle is managed dynamically by the Go run-time.

You can "share" your ZeroMQ socket between multiple Goroutines by using [channels](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) to synchronize access, or by using [mutexes](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex), where you lock access to your socket while a Goroutine is accessing it.

Comment: But why the context object isn't thread (actually, routine) safe? Shouldn't it be?

Comment: ZeroMQ (the C library's) socket implementation is not thread safe, because that's how it was built. To add, you're confusing between ZeroMQ context vs. sockets. Contexts are thread safe, where as the underlying sockets are not. You should be able to create and pass a context between your Goroutines without directly using the underlying socket.

Comment: But a new context is created for each worker in the example I posted. Why, if contexts are thread safe?